# How to show div when page-break occured?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I have this html rows:

```
 <div id=newPage>the new page</div>

 <div ng-repeat="rData in sData.regions | orderBy:'regionType'" style="width:97%; padding:0px 20px 0px 0px; page-break-after:always"></div>
```

As you can see I have page-break-after attribute inside the div. Also I have div with id=newPage the new Page div must be displayed only on print version and only when page-break occurred.

Any idea is it possible to implement?

Comment: On your `print` button's event handler, Can't you check `your_second_div_id.style.pageBreakAfter` 's value and do a style visibility  of `show` or `hide` to the first div?